# 405 on options when implementing security

Tags: symfony, silex

I'm implementing security on my API and I found a road block. I'm using angular, so if the API is on a different host than the client, the client will do a OPTIONS before any POST or put.

This is my code:

```
$app['security.firewalls'] = array(
    'v3' => array(
        'pattern'        => '/v3/.*',   //protect /v3/ endpoints
        'oauth'    => true,         //using oauth service
        'stateless' => true,         //Do not persist this token
    ),
    'default' => [
        'anonymous'  => true,
        'security'   => false,
    ],
);

//We finally register our security using the silex security servide provider
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls' => $app['security.firewalls']
));
```

It works perfect for GET, POST, PUT and DELETE...It don't work for OPTIONS

Comment: Is it related to this bug https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/500c2cd69469f13f3e8007789c0be9039ddb2b56 ? (Just fixed)